# How to create border not around the text, but around box borders?

Tags: flutter

I am trying to create 2 pixel border around box. To get something like:

[image]

```
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(),
    color: Colors.blueGrey
  ),
  child: Container(
    child: Text("Some Text"),
  ),
)
```

But the code above wrap text, so I am getting:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```dart
Container(
  margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
  decoration: BoxDecoration(
    border: Border.all(),
    color: Colors.blueGrey
  ),
  child: Column(
    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.strech,
    children: <Widget>[
      Text('Some Text'),
    ],
  ),
)
```

Answer (score 1):

You are not giving the parent `Container` any size, hence it shrinks to wrap its child. Just set `height` and `width` for the parent container and the border will "widen".
If you want your parent `Container` to fill all the available space, wrap it with a `SizedBox.expand` widget:

```
SizedBox.expand(
child: Container(
    margin: EdgeInsets.all(5),
    decoration: BoxDecoration(
        border: Border.all(),
        color: Colors.blueGrey,
        ),
    child: Container(
            child: Text("Some Text"),
            ),
    )
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Border all class has it's own parameters, you were applying the parameters to the box https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/painting/Border-class.html

```
        Container(
          width: 300, //example height and widths
          height: 100,
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
          color: Colors.amber,
          child: Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.red, width: 2.0)), //Border.all function has it's on parameters
            child: Align(
              child: Text('Some Text'),
            ),
          ),
        )
```

Here's what this code produces
[image]